# Show colorbar as log probability scale in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to show the log probability with colorbar in matplotlib. So I used the following code.

```
hist2d(x, y, bins=50, cmap=plt.cm.cool, alpha=0.75)
colorbar()
```

or

```
hist2d(x, y, bins=50, norm=matplotlib.colors.Norm())
colorbar()
```

However, I can't get the correct one. I can show you what I want.

[image]

This figure is generated by matlab. (not mine) The colorbar shows exactly log probability. How can I do it in matplotlib?

p.s.,

This code

```
hist2d(x, y, bins=50, norm=matplotlib.colors.Norm())
colorbar()
```

generated

[image]

Comment: Can you edit this so your example is reproducible? I.e. add values for x and y

Comment: The problem you have here is that the white areas have zero entries. When you take the log of one of these plots in matplotlib it just gives you a masked white area, as Log(0) is not defined.

Comment: You get exactly the same issue with 2D plots, you cannot go all the way down to zero on a log plot; `lim_{x \to \infty} Log(x) = -\infty` - i.e. the colour scale would have to be infinitely long. You have to decide on some cutoff, and make all values below it equal to that value; which will then add a background to your plot, which may be misleading.

Comment: @mgilbert Here is the code to reproduce it. https://gist.github.com/sangheestyle/111ddf2d3a1b6d7158db Thank you.

Comment: @will agreed! If I do smoothing, it also not really good. I think I need to use just LogNorm and explain about it. Thank you!

Comment: If it is purely an aesthetic thing, you can mask values less than 1, and just make them black, or some colour which would be an extension of your colour scale.